# How to check if my tensorflow is compiled with AVX

Tags: python, tensorflow

There are many posts that explains what it is, how to compile it however couldn't find any that explains ways to check for already installed tensorflow.

I cannot uninstall then re-install with AVX due to permission issue,

I've been training on different servers and some outputs following warning message `This Tensorflow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:AVX2 FMA` while some don't but I'm not sure it is right and sure way of concluding whether installed tensorflow supports AVX.

versions: python3.7, tensorflow2.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled tensorflow with support for SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 and FMA. The build is available here:

> https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build

I hope this is useful.